# How to fine-tune NodeJS server deployed to Azure WebApp for massive load

Tags: node.js, iis, azure-web-app-service, iisnode

I deployed node js server to Azure WebApp, and it worked fine. But, I see that sometime the response time is very slow. Also, I see that somewhere above 500 request/second the server start to fail handling request, and I see it use only 15% CPU. Now, I checked and the server return 500 error because the pipe is busy (by the win32 error code). That's why I was wondering if there is something I can change in the IISNode config to improve the server request capacity.
I already enabled the AlwaysOn feature, and also I add a check in Pingdom to keep the site alive. Also, I already changed nodeProcessCountPerApplication to 0 so it use all the available process.
Thank you,
Omer

Comment: FYI, you should check out [how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to improve the question, if it still not good, I would like to here why.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is enable [Always On](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/04/azure-did-you-know-always-on-web-apps/).  Without it, when your site hasn't been visited for 20 minutes the site gets taken down. Then the next time someone makes a request to your site Azure Web Apps warms up (re-sets up) your site but this process takes a few seconds.

Note that Always On is only available for sites in Basic, Standard, or Premium SKUs

Also, check out this page for tips on debugging Node.js apps in Azure Web Apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/